# How can I reference an existing codebuild project in codepipeline via CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, cicd

I am using AWS CDK to deploy codepipeline and codebuild. What I am current doing is to create codebuild in one cloudformation stack and reference the codebuild in the codepipeline in a different cf stack.

Below is my code, I create a codebuild action like:

```
    const action = new actions.CodeBuildAction({
          actionName: "MockEventBridge",
          type: actions.CodeBuildActionType.BUILD,
          input: input,
          project: new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, name, {
            projectName: mockName,
            environment: {
              computeType: codebuild.ComputeType.SMALL,
              buildImage
              privileged: true,
            },
            role,
            buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename(
              "cicd/buildspec/mockEventbridge.yaml"
            ),
          }),
          runOrder: 1,
        })
    ...
    const stages = {
      stageName, actions: [action]
    }
```

once build the action, I use below code to build codepipeline.

```
new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, name, {
      pipelineName: this.projectName,
      role,
      stages,
      artifactBucket
    });
```

The problem is that both the codebuild project and codepipeline are built into one stack. If I build the codebuild project in a separate cf stack, how can I reference this stack in codepipeline?

when look at the api reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline.Pipeline.html, I can't find a way to reference the codebuild arn in codepipeline instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `codebuild.Project.fromProjectArn` [static method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.Project.html#static-fromwbrprojectwbrarnscope-id-projectarn) to [import an external Project resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_importing) using its ARN.  It returns an `IProject`, which is what your pipeline's `actions.CodeBuildAction` [props expect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildActionProps.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **export** value to export the resource Codebuild created in another Stack.
The exported CodeBuild from the first Stack can be **imported** in the new Stack of CodePipeline.

You can see this page for more info https://lzygo1995.medium.com/how-to-export-and-import-stack-output-values-in-cdk-ff3e066ca6fc

Comment: I am more asking about what the syntax I can use in build the codepipeline instance. I have looked at the codepipeline api reference but can't find a way to pass the arn of codebuild project